# Symmetric matrix transforming a matrix into its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

I find myself unable to understand the argument on page 893 in this article https://msp.org/pjm/1959/9-3/pjm-v9-n3-p25-s.pdf
I cannot see why there n^2-n equations (I thought that it was linked to the dimension of the space of symmetric matrices, but it does not seem to be the case) and I cannot see why it implies that there is at least n linearly independent solutions of the system (I thought of the rank-nullity theorem but i don't see how we can apply it here)
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The fact that a matrix is symmetric can be rewritten as $$\frac{n^2-n}{2}$$ linear equations (which are the equations $m_{ij}=m_{ji}$, for $i<j$).

So the fact that *two* matrices are symmetric can be rewritten as $n^2-n$ linear equations.

2. For your second question, you have $n^2-n$ equations over a space of dimension $n^2$, so the rank-nullity theorem gives that the space of solutions has dimension $\geq n^2-(n^2-n)=n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer for the first question but in the second question, which kernel and which image do you use to apply the rank-nullity theorem ?

Comment: You have a system of $n^2-n$ equations over a space of dimension $n^2$, so you can write this system $MX=0$, where $M$ is a matrix with $n^2$ columns and $n^2-n$ rows. Now the rank of this matrix must be $\leq n^2-n$ because it has only $n^2-n$ rows, so you deduce by the rank-nullity theorem that its kernel (which is precisely the space of all solutions) has dimension $\geq n$.